# Partial color in bottom border to show progress bar

Tags: css

Is there a way to use a linear-gradient to set a two-color bottom border so that it can be used as a progress bar?  Think about the way Safari shows you the progress bar for when a website is loading.

We can do it using background:

```
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, green 10%, red 0%, red 100%);
```

This would generate a div that's 10% green and 90% red. Can a similar technique be used on the bottom border of the div?  Also, can the width of this bottom border be controlled so that it's 3px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather create an element for it, but you can do something like this:

Please don't use green and red due to color blindness issues.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  --progress: 10%;

  background-color: khaki;
  height: 3rem;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  
  border-image: linear-gradient(90deg, green var(--progress), red 0%, red 100%) 1;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

[EDIT] I can add how I would set up a progress bar with pseudo-elements. I would prefer using two (one as a background; another as progress), so it's easier to animate the progress.

Added a range input to make it a little bit more interactive.

```js
let headerElements = document.querySelectorAll('header');

function updateHeaders(value) {
  headerElements.forEach((header) => {
    header.style.setProperty('--progress', value + "%");
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  --primary-color: lightblue;
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  --progress: 30%;

  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* RELEVANT CSS */
  position: relative;
}

  /* RELEVANT CSS */
header.progressbar::before,
header.two.pseudo-elements.progressbar::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 3px;
}

header.one.pseudo-element.progressbar::before {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, green var(--progress), red 0%, red 100%);
}

header.two.pseudo-elements.progressbar::before {
  z-index: 2;
  right: initial;
  width: var(--progress);
  background-color: green;
  transition: width 300ms linear;
}

header.two.pseudo-elements.progressbar::after {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

/* PLACEHOLDER CSS BELOW */
input[type="range"] {
  margin: 1rem 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

div[title="Logotype"] {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

header > a {
  padding: 0px 0.5rem;
  color: #121212;
}
```

```html
<h3>One pseudo-element</h3>
<header class="one pseudo-element progressbar">
  <div title="Logotype">L</div>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
</header>

<h3>Two pseudo-elements</h3>
<header class="two pseudo-elements animate progressbar">
  <div title="Logotype">L</div>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
</header>

<input type="range" oninput="updateHeaders(this.value)" value="30" />
```

Comment: Interested that you'd rather use a separate element for this. Is there an accessibility reason or something else?

Comment: It's more of a programming convention. Let each element do one thing, not several. Like in my example: `header` should display elements in the header (as a container), not also display the progress. I would rather add a div or a pseudo-element with absolute positioning within the `header`. This makes even more sense when you use custom elements with functionality (CSS, javascript) contained within them.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't really thought about that before.

Comment: Thanks. Good point about not using red and green due to color blindness. How can we use a pseudo-element with absolute positioning within the header to do the same thing? The reason I'm trying to avoid creating a new element for progress bar is because the header is sticky at the top and I'm not a CSS expert, so introducing new elements could mess with the existing layout.

Comment: No worries. I edited the post with two examples of how it can look like.